# kohana synapses studio project template

Tags: kohana, project-template

We started using the kohana project template from synapses studio :

https://github.com/synapsestudios/kohana-projecttemplate

It's great but the problem is that there is no real documentation for it and I haven't been able to find a good tutorial about it. Basically you need to read every modules' documentation to get an overview of it, quite a pain and complicated to accomplish.

I think what is missing here is a get-started tutorial....

Would someone know where to find info on how to start with it, like configuring the database and htaccesses etc, or maybe be able to write a simple tutorial on the first steps to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually after some searching I found this :

https://github.com/patricksebastien/kohana-3.2-example

This approach is a little different than the synapses studio, but it's great anyway!

Simple, self-explanatory, and already implementing i18n and Authentication, installed in 2 minutes!